# IIS Reverse proxy for 2 sites with different SSL certificate

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

I had a CNAME configured with a GoDaddy account, we'll name it as cname.myCompany.com. cname the CNAME I named it as myCompany.com as my parent domain. myCompany.com has it's own SSL certificate.

cname (cname.myCompany.com) value points to www.compendiumblog.com (w/c it's own SSL certificate)

Now, when I do https://cname.myCompany.com - it loads the page but with broken SSL certificate.

I tried solving this with IIS (Server 2012R2) reverse proxy but it doesn't seem to work. I installed AAR and enabled Reverse Proxy.

From IIS, I created a new server farm named as blog.myCompany.com. Unchecked "Enable SSL offloading" in Routing Rules and from URL rewrite Inbound rule I set the action as ReWrite. Rewrite value as https://cname.myCompany.com/{R:0} and set a Server Variable as HTTP_X_COMPENDIUM_ID = e7dff869-c319-43c9-9bf1-eca9b46gb5de. Save the setting but it does not work.

How do I go with reverse proxying with IIS?

Comment: No worries.. I managed to work a solution.

Comment: may we have the chance to know your solution?

Comment: This question in its current form lacks of key information. If you already have a site on IIS with HTTPS site binding for `www.compendiumblog.com`, and want to support `cname.myCompany.com` there, then simply add another HTTPS binding for the latter. The key on Windows Server 2012 R2 is to use the new SNI support it provides, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#sni-based-bindings

Answer (score -1):

Right click on your site name and select bindings.

You have to create an HTTPS binding per rewritten site

On **ALL** your HTTPS bindings , please check the "**Require Server Name Indicaton**" check box.

This will force IIS to check for a dns name input and will allow different certificates on other HTTPS bindings.
without this settings , only one certificate is allowed per site.

Hope this will help someone

Comment: There was never a limitation of "only one certificate is allowed per site". A single IIS site can support multiple HTTPS bindings (aka multiple certificates) from long long ago.